# How to subtract an irregular portion from a shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, mask, selections

using photoshop I have this shape over a regular circle shape. I need to subtract from the circle the portion marked in black. I was able to select the circle portion to be subtracted but here I stop.

[image]

Is it possible to subtract from a shape a selection? Or is there a more simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the Ellipse Tool to create your circle shape. Be sure to select 'Shape' as the tool mode.
2. Select the Pen Tool and choose 'Subtract Front Shape' in the Path Operations. This will make your ellipse vanish, just undo (Ctrl + Z).

[image: Tool Mode | Path Operations]

3. Now use the Pen Tool to draw your irregular portion.

[image: Subtract Front Shape]

Is this what you needed?

Comment: @Ritardi.Net if this answers your question, I would suggest marking the answer as right as it will help people who might have the same problem in the future :)